What should and shouldn't be done with this brush?
I bought a set of brushes, which look like this:

It feels like fairly harsh plastic, its not as fluffy as I imagined it. Can I probably use this on all surfaces? What should I avoid using it on?
This is not a brush for dust more like foam? So probably for hard plastic interior and wheels?
